# Symfony - set @SerializedName() dynamically

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

is there a way to access serializer metadata, similar to doctrines mapping/classmetadata?
Doctrine allows you to edit mapping information via `loadClassMetadata($args)` from an `EventSubscriber`.

I'd like to edit my `@SerializedName("foo")` annotation pre serialization.

For context, the attributes (and therefore Entites) are inside a symfony bundle and need to be renamed based on the main applications settings.

I'm using symfonys serializer, not JMS.

Is it possible to call functions inside annotaions,  which would look like this: `@SerializedName(getName())`? That could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution didn't get me far, though I found something that worked for me.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;


public function __construct(ClassMetadataFactoryInterface $classMetadataFactory){
   $this->classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
}
```

in my function which is called before the actual serialization:

```
$classMetadata = $this->classMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('fully qualified classname');
$attributesMetadata = $classMetadata->getAttributesMetadata();

foreach ($attributesMetadata as $attr) {
    $attr->addGroup(['exampleGroup']);
    $attr->setSerializedName('examplename');
}
```

That way I can change the metadata dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom normalizer for this class and change it as you wish
https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html

Comment: thanks for answering, I will take a look at this tomorrow and see how far this gets me.